# Is this a Lipschitz continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, lipschitz-functions

Is $$\frac{xy}{1 + x^2 + y^2}$$ Lipschitz continuous on $x^2 + y^2 \le 4$?

I've tried using Cauchy-Schwarz intequality but got nothing. I also tried to find out whether $xy$ is Lipschitz but failed as well.

Any hints on this problem?

EDIT: I need to exhibit the Lipschitz constant if there is one.

Comment: Do you know a sufficient condition for a function to be Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: If there is a constant $C$ such that $||F(x_1, y_1)| + |F(x_2, y_2)|| \le ||(x_1 - x_2, y_1 - y_2) ||$ for all pairs of points on the region of interest?

Comment: Related to differentiability?

Comment: Being continuously differentiable, right?

Comment: this is not true in general, $x^2$ is continuously differentiable but only locally lipschitz :D

Comment: Well, $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuously differentiable on $(0,1)$, but not Lipschitz. What is the crucial difference?

Comment: That for $1/x$ there is no open set containing $[0, 1]$ within which the function is $\mathcal{C}^1$. But there is for $x^2 + y^2 \le 4$?

Comment: Look also at user_Fibonacci_sequence's example.

Comment: Since the function is $\mathcal{C}^1$ and $x^2 + y^2 \le 4$ is a compact set, because of Heine-Borel theorem we can take a minimum Lipschitz constant. Therefor it's Lipschitz.

Comment: Righty-ho. The considered set is compact. Therefore the derivative is bounded. And the set is convex.

Comment: Now how can I find its Lipschitz constant?

Comment: Since the domain is convex, the "best" Lipschitz constant is the supremum of the absolute value of the gradient.

Comment: And why is that?

Comment: 1) Independent how the domain looks like, the absolute value of the gradient at any point is bounded above by the Lipschitz constant. 2) On the other direction. Since the domain is convex, you can join any two point by a line segment in the domain. You can then express the difference of the function at the two points as a integral involving the gradient and hence bound it by the product of the supremum of absolute values of gradient and the distance. This implies that supremum is an upper bound for the Lipschitz constant too.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x,y)=\frac {xy}{1+x^2+y^2}$ is $C^1$ because the partial derivatives are continuous.Thus it's Lipschitz con.